# Javascript append tr to table

Tags: javascript, function

Hi I have a function where I need to append the result to the end of the table but it gives me an error "that the Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object."

Here is my code

```
window.onload = function() {
    var mainTable = document.getElementById('mainTable');
    var types = document.getElementsByClassName('typeCell');
    var rentType = "Rent";

    for (var i = 0; i<types.length; i++) {
        if(types[i].innerHTML.trim() == rentType) {

            mainTable.appendChild(types[i].parentNode.outerHTML.trim());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is because `outerHTML` returns a string, not a node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `types[i].parentNode.outerHTML.trim()` you are giving a string to the functon `mainTable.appendChild` and, as the error said, you have to give an HTML element.

Modify your code to have `mainTable.appendChild(types[i].parentNode.clone());` in your if condition (I'm not sure about this solution because I cannot test it, but it should be something like that).

Comment: actually when I type mainTable.appendChild(types[i].parentNode.cloneNode(true)); 
and the browser crashes, any ideas why

Comment: Can you put your page on JSFiddle please? It will be easier for me to help you.

Answer (score 0):

types[i].parentNode.outerHTML.trim()  just can return a String

but  the argument of "Node.appendChild()"  must be a Object